# How does gensim.models.FatText.wv.wmdistance calculate between two documents?

Tags: python-3.x, gensim, fasttext

I already have a training model for fastText with gensim, and
I can get the distance between two sentence as described below,

```
sentence_1 = "Today is very cold."  
sentence_2 = "I'd like something to drink."    

print(model.wv.wmdistance(sentence_1.split(" "), sentence_2.split(" ")))
# 0.8446287678977793  # for example
```

but how does `vmdistance` calculate this value?
I'd like to know the formula.

API documents: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.Doc2VecKeyedVectors.distance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wmdistance()` function calculates the "Word Mover's Distance" between two sets-of-words.

You can view the academic paper which coined the "Word Mover's Distance" (WMD) measure, via the application of an older idea from operations research called "Earth Mover's Distance" to text, at:

[From Word Embeddings To Document Distances](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/kusnerb15.pdf), by Matt Kusner et al

You can view the exact code used by gensim's `wmdistance()` function at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/de0dcc39fee0ae4eaf45d79bd5418d32780f9aa5/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L677

WMD is fairly time-consuming to calculate, as it involves a search through many possible "shifts" of the "piles of meaning" for a minimal-expenditure approach. It becomes especially time-consuming as the texts become longer. (It's more practical for short sentences than full paragraphs or documents.)

Often texts are instead summarized into a single vectors – via either an averaging of their word-vectors, or a shallow text-to-vector algorithm like `Doc2Vec`, or a deep-learning model (BERT, ELMo, etc). Then those single vectors can be far more quickly compared via simple cosine-similarity. (That's what the plain `similarity()` or `distance()` methods of gensim's vector models do.)

Comment: Interesting! I want to know the difference of ability between the WMD and the single-vectors. I'll try. Thank you for a kind answer.